# For loop rows and columns of a list

Tags: c#, list

I am new in C# and I have a problem with for loops in lists.
I have a list with numbers (called alpha) which go from 0 to 7.

```
alpha0=1
alpha1=2
alpha2=3
...
alpha7=8
```

Now I want to create a matrix containing all these alphas in this way and then I want to transpose it:

[image: IMG1]

I've tried to write the transposed one directly but it gives me error or better I am wrong with the syntax (see last string of my code). Could somebody help me?

I called startinglist my list with alphas.

```
 List<List<double>> arr = new List<List<double>>();
 for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
   for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++)
      arr[col, row].Add(startinglist[col]);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi @Sentry it gives me 2 errors in the final line: "No overload for method this takes 2 arguments" and "Argument1: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.list<double> to <double>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try this:</s>

```
var size = 8;
int[] alpha = Enumerable.Range(1, size).ToArray();
int[][] C = new int[size - 1][];

for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++)
{
  C[i] = new int[size];
  C[i][i] = alpha[i];
  C[i][i + 1] = 1 - alpha[i + 1];
}
```

**Edit:**
Since you have alpha already defined as a list, you may use this:

**Edit2:**
Changed int to double:

```
double[][] C = new double[alpha.Count - 1][];

for(int i = 0 ; i < alpha.Count - 1; i++)
{
  C[i] = new double[alpha.Count];
  C[i][i] = alpha[i];
  C[i][i + 1] = 1 - alpha[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sohaib thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately my alpha is already a list of numbers and I don't know why I can't use it since your code gives me as error "a local variable or function named alpha is already defined in this scope"

Comment: Hi Sohaib, it still tells me that "Cannot implicitly conver type System.Collections.Generic.list<double> to int"

Comment: Still the same error but with "System.Collections.Generic.list<double>". The error is at line: C[i][i] = alpha[i];

Comment: how are you defining alpha?

Comment: This is how I've already defined alpha:                                       
List<List<double>> alpha = new List<List<double>>();

            for (int i= m; i<= m ;i++)
            {
                for (int j = iniz; j < Listbeta.Count; j += m + i)
                {
                    alpha.Add(Listbeta.GetRange(j, i));
                    iniz = iniz+i;
                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: Ok the reason is that my alpha is a list made by lists. I should see how to manage the first list which is the one i want to work on.

Comment: based on your question, alpha must be a list or an array, not list of lists or 2d array

Comment: Yes I know but I made it simpler in order to avoid to explain all my code. Do you know how it is possible to create matric C using only one of a list of alpha? When you write double[][] C = new double[alpha.Count - 1][], the double [] indicates row and columns, right? Sorry but I'm new in C#

Comment: The double [] is to create a 2d array, which could represent matrices.
The code snippet above is supposed to create the C matrix (as shown in the image) based on one list of alpha.
Just define alpha as follow:
List<double> alpha = new List<double>{values};
and replace "values" with the actual values of the list, separated by commas

Comment: Ok thanks. If I want to access to one of the alpha matrix could I just pust alpha(1) for example or is not possible in c#?

Comment: you may access the list values as you access an array, e.g.: alpha[0]

Comment: Hi @SohaibJundi how can I do now if alpha is a list made by 2 lists? I have alpha[1] = [1...8], alpha[2] = [3,1,..8]. Therefore I expect two C matrix. I'm stuck with this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
  var size = 8;
  var alpha = Enumerable.Range(1, size).ToArray();
  var matrix = new int[size, size + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    // Assign values on the diagonal.
    matrix[i, i] = alpha[i];
    matrix[i, i + 1] = 1 - alpha[i];
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to use my alpha list without defining it as you did? Unfortunately my alpha will assume different values inside a for loop in the future

Comment: @Roberto Just pass it as parameter to your method. You can any `Enumerable` here.

Comment: In your code it gives me as error "Cannot implictly convert type System.Collections.GenericList<double> to int" referred to matrix[i, i] = alpha[i]; Also it tells me that "alpha is already defined in this scope" reffered to var alpha = Enumerable.Range(1, size).ToArray(). That's why I asked you :(